# All variations of matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to write an algorithm for getting all possible variations of a matrix in JavaScript.
Here is what I want to achieve:

```
blue,red
male,female,other
small,medium,large

-----------------

blue,male,small
blue,male,medium
blue,male,large

blue,female,small,
blue,female,medium,
blue,female,large

blue,other,small,
blue,other,medium,
blue,other,large

red,male,small
red,male,medium
red,male,large

red,female,small,
red,female,medium,
red,female,large

red,other,small,
red,other,medium,
red,other,large
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wht you want is called the Cartesian product of several lists. If you have a fixed set of lists, nested loops are an easy way to generate the Cartesian product.

You can generalize this for an arbitrary list by iterating through the lists in odometer style. (Each digit of the odometer may have a different range, though.)

Here's how:

```
function cartesian(m) {
    const res = [];
    const index = [];    // current index
    const max = [];      // length of sublists

    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        index.push(0);
        max.push(m[i].length);
    }

    for (;;) {
        res.push(index.map((i, j) => m[j][i]));

        let i = 0;
        index[i]++;

        while (index[i] == max[i]) {
            index[i] = 0;
            i++;

            if (i == m.length) return res;
            index[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
const m = [
    ["blue", "red"],
    ["male", "female", "other"],
    ["small", "medium", "large"],
];

const p = cartesian(m);
```

This creates one huge list of all possibilities, which probably isn't ideal. You can change the function by doing whatever you want to do with each possibilitiy where the code above pushes to current list to the result array. The code above changes the first item in each iteration, which is the opposite of what you show in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through arrays using reduce:

```js
let data = ['blue','red']
let data2 =['male','female','other']
let data3 =['small','medium','large']

let result = data.reduce((acc,rec) => {
 
  return acc.concat(data2.reduce((acc2, rec2) => {
    
    return acc2.concat(data3.reduce((acc3,rec3) =>{
      
      return acc3.concat([`${rec}, ${rec2}, ${rec3}`])
    },[]))
  },[]))
},[])

console.log(result)
```